# How to copy Firefox extensions in Ubuntu to a Container with Ubuntu?

Tags: firefox, root, firefox-extensions, add-on

**Hi**

What I'm looking for is to be able to pass the extensions already installed, that is to say to pass the directory of extensions and the corresponding Firefox and overwrite in the **Firefox directories** of my **Ubuntu Container**.

but I can't find where the installed extensions are saved, in the **Firefox** documentation it indicates that they should be saved in the **/Home** directory in a hidden folder called **/.mozilla** and inside an **/extensions** sub directory. However in this directory there is absolutely nothing is empty

I hope your support and **thank you very much.**

Comment: For what purpose? If you create an account in FF you can conect to another account through your FF account. Is that not what you mean?

Comment: No friend, my purpose is to be able to install my extensions in the Firefox of my container, but without the use of the graphic section.